# How to sort directly from the relationship in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a one to many relationship between table company and table employee like companyA.employees and employeeA.company. And now I want to find the youngest employee in companyA.

I know I can achieve it by one of the followings

1. use order_by when declaring the relationship
2. use order_by with query

But does sqlalchemy have a builtin feature to sort it from companyA.employees directly without the penalty to get all employees from companyA first? Thanks!

Comment: Sorting and getting the top element will al be done on the database side. Write a query with `.order_by()` and `.limit(1)`, print the SQL, and `explain plan` for it in your database. I bet the optimizer is smart enough to avoid sorting and will find the minimum element instead. SQLAlchemy will definitely not fetch all elements and do the sorting on Python side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I think what you mean is the method 2 I mentioned. But what I'm looking for is a way to write code like companyA.employees.sort(key='age')[0] instead of session.query(Employee)...sort_by(Employee.age).first(). I feel it's more transparent to the upper layer without knowing database at all. I'm not sure if it's possible or if it's a good practice.

Comment: See: you actually don't need to sort the employees by age and take the first of them. You want to find the employee with lowest age, but you come via a (slow) imperative route because you don't see any other. For that, I'd add an explicit method, like `A.employess.min_by('age')`, or even `A.employees.top_by('age', reverse=True)`, that would do the right thing under the hood. You'd be free to implement it in a way you see fit, and change the implementation without changing the clients.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean sqlalchemy has min_by or top_by API built-in or I need to implement myself? If I need to implement myself, as far as I can think of, it's either query underneath again or custom sorting after I fetch the whole table. That's the two things I both want to avoid. Probably it's impossible then. Thanks!

Comment: No, but if you can add it. And implementing it is pretty easy. I thought you wanted you upper levels of code to see a nicer API than raw SQLAlchemy; providing custom methods that do something requiring a complicated query seems natural.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking is this:

```
session.query(Employee).with_parent(companyA, Company.employees).order_by(Employee.age).limit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the neat answer but what I'm looking for is a way to avoid using session.query at all. But I guess it's just impossible.

Comment: @Hanks Well you need to get the data somehow. If not with a query, what else?

Comment: But companyA.employees (employees is the relationship claimed in the Company table) also gets the data but without letting people notice it's using sqlalchemy. I was wondering if we can even do companyA.employees.sort_by('age') or sort_by(companyA.employees, 'age') with sqlalchemy built-in features.

Comment: @Hanks So you want a way to say `companyA.employees[0]` but without loading `companyA.employees` first? You can make it a dynamic relationship (you'll of course need to apply the `order_by` on the relationship itself).

Comment: Is this the first method I mentioned? Based on my understanding, that needs to hardcode order_by('age') in the relationship (e.g. in Company table, employees = relationship('Employee', order_by='age'). This is not flexible since later I may want to find the tallest employee.

Comment: @Hanks Then you need to apply `order_by` at query time. `companyA.employees.order_by(Employee.age)[0]`.

Comment: So this is actually valid? I didn't find order_by method from the return of companyA.employees and I thought companyA.employees is a property...

Comment: @Hanks If you set it up as a dynamic relationship, `companyA.employees` is a `Query` object.

Comment: Thanks! I think that's what I'm looking for!